# Since 15.04 my WiFi router is sometimes not seen after boot

Tags: boot, networking, wireless, 15.04, internet

Starting exactly with the reboot after upgrading from 14.10 to 15.04 July 25th, I have a new problem:
Sometimes, on booting, I have no internet.

When this happens, the Network Manager Menu shows "Wi-Fi Networks Disconnected" & does not show my own Router but still shows neighbours' Routers.

I tried to include a maybe-helpful screenshot of the Network menus in good/bad conditions but am not allowed, sorry!!!

I can fix the problem every time by Disabling & Re-enabling either Wi-Fi or Networking from that menu.

The problem seems to occur at random, 15 times out of 49 boots since I started noting.

I have been using the same router OK since Feb 2012.

The same PC & LAN since August 2014.

Prior to 15.04, I had 14.04 then 14.10 on the same partition OK.

Since August 2014, the same PC continues to multi-boot 14.04LTS & W8 with no problem.

Other PC's & mobile phones continue to connect OK.

So I suppose it is linked to the upgrade to 15.04.

I would appreciate any suggestions for diagnosing & fixing this problem!

Thanks!

Comment: Please follow https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html and attach any logs.

Comment: Sorry, I have not had time to look at this recently, but the problem continues with 31 fails vs 67 successful connections to date.
I can always connect by 2 clicks on "Enable WiFi".

Comment: Today I started to work through the 15.04 Wireless Troubleshooter (thanks for that link) but immediately hit a problem.
When I enter nm-tool in Terminal, I get:
"No command 'nm-tool' found, did you mean:
 Command 'dm-tool' from package 'lightdm' (main)
nm-tool: command not found"
Searching, I found nm-tools is no longer included in 15.04 & has been replaced by nmcli but I don't see how I would use that.
I don't want to accidentally use this "more powerful cli tool" to screw things up further!
What is my next logical step?
Thanks!

Comment: Seems like they forgot to update the documentation. Replace nm-tool with nmcli, the rest is hopefully valid.

Comment: Entering "nmcli" in Terminal just gives me a list of OPTIONS & OBJECTS which I don't understand.

Which combinations (exact text to enter) are necessary or interesting to troubleshoot?

Comment: I should mention my WiFi adapter is a Penguin Wireless N USB Adapter /w External Antenna for GNU / Linux (TPE-N150USBL) which should be robust for Ubuntu?

Comment: I ran "ifconfig" & "sudo lshw -C network" in Good & Bad situations.

But I don't see how to attach the results here (size limit).

Answer (score 0):

It could help to set it as a "system connection" in the network settings.

If this doesn't work, you can force your network to rescan by doing:

```
sudo iwlist scanning
```